# Laravelのコマンドラインプログラムでパラメータが認識されず落ちてしまいます．

Tags: laravel, command-line

Laravel 初心者の質問です．

### 現象

次のような簡単なLaravelのコマンドラインプログラムを作ってみたのですが、

ElasticIndexMaker.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands\User;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class ElasticIndexMaker extends Command
{
    /**
     * The name and signature of the console command.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    //protected $signature = 'elasticindexmaker {index: Index specified by the target S3 directry structure starting first character with slash}';
    protected $signature = "elasticindexmaker {index: Index name}";

    /**
     * The console command description.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $description = 'Generate Elasticsearch index';

    /**
     * Create a new command instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $index = $this -> argument("index");
        $verboseLog = $this -> option("verbose");

        $this->info("Index: " . $index);
        if ($this->confirm("Are you sure to generate index by this parameter?")) {
        } else {
            return;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

kernel.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Console;

use Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel as ConsoleKernel;

class Kernel extends ConsoleKernel
{
    /**
     * The Artisan commands provided by your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $commands = [
        Commands\User\ElasticIndexMaker::class
    ];

    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        // $schedule->command('inspire')->hourly();
    }

    /**
     * Register the commands for the application.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function commands()
    {
        $this->load(__DIR__.'/Commands');

        require base_path('routes/console.php');
    }
}
```

#### 1. -h だとパラメータ index は認識されているみたいです

```
PS D:\My_Documents\proj\Elasticsearch\index-gen-laravel> php artisan elasticindexmaker -h     
Description:
  Generate Elasticsearch index

Usage:
  elasticindexmaker <index: Index name>

Arguments:
  index: Index name     

Options:
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command    
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi            Force ANSI output
      --no-ansi         Disable ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug
PS D:\My_Documents\proj\Elasticsearch\index-gen-laravel>
```

#### 2. 実際にパラメータを指定して動かすと例外になります．

ところが 実際にパラメータを指定して使ってみるとエラーで落ちてしまいます．（中で例外が起こっています．）

```
PS D:\My_Documents\proj\Elasticsearch\index-gen-laravel> php artisan elasticindexmaker aa/bb

  The "index" argument does not exist.  

PS D:\My_Documents\proj\Elasticsearch\index-gen-laravel>
```

VSCodeでデバッグしてみると以下で引っかかっているようです．（画像見れるでしょうか？）何かパラメータの`index`が認識されていないみたいです．

```
Exception has occurred.
Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException: No arguments expected for "elasticindexmaker" command, got "aa/bb".
```

[image: 例外発生個所]

どこがまずいのか教示いただければ幸いです．

### 環境

Windows 10 + VSCodeでやっています．

以下composer.jsonからの抜粋です．

```
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php": "^3.171",
        "aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel": "^3.6",
        "elasticsearch/elasticsearch": "^7.10",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5"
    },
```

不足情報ありましたらお知らせください．

以上 よろしくお願いいたします．

Answer (score 0):

失礼しました．自己RESです．本家Stackoverflowに聞いたら30秒で解決しました．`index`の後のスペース1文字の問題でした．

app/Console/Commands/User/ElasticIndexMaker.php （修正後）

```
protected $signature = "elasticindexmaker {index : Index name}";
```

実行画面

[image: 実行画面スナップショット]